# How to get sound duration in AppInventor?

Tags: app-inventor

Is it possible to obtain information on the duration (in milliseconds) of a sound file used in AppInventor, or does it have to be hardcoded (for example, 90000ms for song.mp3)?

I need that information to be able to set a looping background music with the clock component. The logic is that the TimerInterval property is set dynamically to chosen sound duration - it could be 60000ms if one song is chosen, it could be something else if another song is chosen, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in Player component does not offer that feature
but there is the [Player extension](https://puravidaapps.com/player.php), which offers a **Duration** property.

However to be able to loop some music you do not need the duration of the music, just set property **Loop** of the built in Player component to true and the music loops automatically... btw. the extension also offers a Loop event in case you need it...